# Unable to remove a container disk on MacBook Pro SSD

Tags: disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

I am trying to remove a container disk and exFat partition on the GUID partitioned SSD on my Macbook Pro 13" 128GB early 2015. It got created by BOOT CAMP ASSISTANT. It is taking up 29GB of space on my disk. There is also a small exFat partition that I cannot remove. In disk utility the option to delete this partition and container disk is greyed out. When I press partition when I have selected my SSD and click on the 29GB container disk, the - button is greyed out, and in the bottom right corner it says "You cannot remove this volume because the previous volume cannot be resized". I have tried doing this when booted into Recovery mode 'Command + R'

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

EDIT: I formatted 'container disk 1' as 'untitled' and as exFAT out of curiosity and it deleted the container disk, but it added another volume called 'untitled' under the 'APPLE SSD SM0128...' which cannot be deleted (greyed out remove button).

Comment: APFS Containers are not created by Boot Camp, they are created by macOS. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299840/is-it-safe-to-remove-apfs-containers

Answer (score -1):

In your screen shot I can see 2 additional containers just bellow disk1, these must be removed first. Start by removing the containers going clockwise from macOS. You will then be able to remove disk1 last.

Comment: Both the volumes below container disk 1 cannot be deleted, their - buttons are also greyed out

Comment: The only volume I can delete is 'macOS' which I would obviously not want to do.